# Input Arithmetic Operators Only in Masked TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

I am creating application in windows form in c#

I know that in masked textbox, we can restrict the format of input, and also restrict the which type of input we can validate like numbers only, characters only, alphanumeric.
But now I am trying to put restriction on the masked text (or simple textbox) to accept a single arithmetic operator (+ or - or * or /) only. I have searched the web but didn't find a way. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Winforms, web forms, WPF, GTK+, ...?

Comment: @jdphenix windows form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier way would be limit the  Max Length characters to 1 in textbox properties

and in the TextChanged  event you can write

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
  {
    char[] SpecialChars = "+-*/".ToCharArray();
    int indexOf = textBox1.Text.IndexOfAny(SpecialChars);
    if (indexOf == -1)
     {
      textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
      MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid Character")
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Becose its accepting only single character i think masked Textbox is not nessasary, so i did it in simple TextBox

Comment: You explained it well in code, and that works great. I need another this also. I need to restrict at the time of entering input. I mean, when I press any arithmetic operator in textbox, it is entered, but if I press any key, other than arithmetic operators, it should not type in the textbox. Just like 00000 mask for integers only. Is it possible ?

Comment: Since it is only single character textbox, it will clear the text as soon as user enter, if it is not expected character.

Comment: wow! thats great, now it works. Thanks for helping me. I have marked your answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular `TextBox`. `MaskedTextBox` won't meet your needs. In a very simple form example, use an event handler like this for `KeyPress` on the `TextBox`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  var accepted = new[] {'+', '-', '*', '/', (char)Keys.Back};
  if (!accepted.Intersect(new[] {e.KeyChar}).Any()) {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

and set the `TextBox.MaxLength` property to `1`.